# DVD won't autoplay

Tags: 12.10, launcher, dvd

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10

I accidentally unlocked the dvd icon from the launcher, and now I can't get the icon back. Also, dvds won't auto-play any more.

Yes, I tried googling for solutions, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for the same solution and every search I've made on the web brought me to how-to's that are outdated, as this has changed a bit on a few versions ago.
So I started digging on every single setting in the settings screen and I've found it!
I can't understand the logic in it, but to find the autoplay settings for different type of media you need to go to "System Settings" then on the "System" category click on "Details"
Go figure!!
To lock the icon on the launcher is easy, you need to run it manually once, and while it's running you right click on icon and select "Lock to Launcher"
This is valid for any application, btw

I hope this helps

Comment: I see that you have edited this and rejected your edit. I would suggest that you just delete this and use your registered account to post your answer. Thank you.